# lapply function to pass single and + arguments to LM

Tags: r

I am stuck trying to pass "+" arguments to `lm`.

My 2 lines of code below work fine for single arguments like:

```
model_combinations=c('.', 'Long', 'Lat', 'Elev')


lm_models = lapply(model_combinations, function(x) {
                               lm(substitute(Y ~ i, list(i=as.name(x))), data=climatol_ann)})
```

But same code fails if I add 'Lat+Elev' at end of list of model_combinations as in:

```
model_combinations=c('.', 'Long', 'Lat', 'Elev', 'Lat+Elev')
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Lat+Elev' not found

I've scanned posts but am unable to find solution.

Comment: Names can't contain a +. That isn't valid syntax. If it was how would you sum two variables? You need an expression. Anyway, use sprintf and as.formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've generally found it more robust/easier to understand to use `reformulate` to construct formulas via string manipulations rather than trying to use `substitute()` to modify an expression, e.g.

```
model_combinations <- c('.', 'Long', 'Lat', 'Elev', 'Lat+Elev')
model_formulas <- lapply(model_combinations,reformulate,
                         response="Y")
lm_models <- lapply(model_formulas,lm,data=climatol_ann)
```

Because `reformulate` works at a string level, it doesn't have a problem if the elements are themselves non-atomic (e.g. `Lat+Elev`). The only tricky situation here is if your `data` argument or variables are constructed in some environment that can't easily be found, but passing an explicit `data` argument usually avoids problems.

(You can also use `as.formula(paste(...))` or `as.formula(sprintf(...))`; `reformulate()` is just a convenient wrapper.)

Comment: Works great! Much appreciated!

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

With `as.formula` you can do:

`models = lapply(model_combinations,function(x) lm(as.formula(paste("y ~ ",x)),  data=climatol_ann))`

For the mtcars dataset:

`model_combs = c("hp","cyl","hp+cyl")
testModels = lapply(model_combs,function(x) lm(as.formula(paste("mpg ~ ",x)), data=mtcars) )`

```
testModels

#[[1]]
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = as.formula(paste("mpg ~ ", x)), data = mtcars)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           hp  
#   30.09886     -0.06823  
#
#
#[[2]]
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = as.formula(paste("mpg ~ ", x)), data = mtcars)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          cyl  
#     37.885       -2.876  
#
#
#[[3]]
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = as.formula(paste("mpg ~ ", x)), data = mtcars)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           hp          cyl  
#   36.90833     -0.01912     -2.26469
```